# Photoshop: how to print logo without a gray background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, mask, background-removal

I've tried a lot of different things already: inversed it, added a layer mask, trimmed the transparent pixels and deleted the background. It still prints with a gray background to my image. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Im doing iron-on and I want the logo to be the only ink on the image so that I don't iron on a white or gray or any color background to it. . now that I have it masked, if I can find a way to delete the black part of the mask (if you see in the image) i'll be golden. or something else? i really don't know at this point

Comment: how are you printing it, directly from Photoshop? what are the printing settings? Are you exporting to another software? which file format? I see the layer is a smart object; what happens if you print directly from Illustrator?

Comment: In most printing processes, such as inkjet printing and CMYK process printing, there is no white ink used.  Have you tried simply printing with a regular white background. Ink should not be applied to white areas.

Comment: Probably too late now, but do your logos in ILLUSTRATOR ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Right click on the layer mask and choose to apply it. The grey background could most likely be related to the way your layer mask was applied OR the color profile you're working with.

For example, if you used brush for the mask, you must ensure you are using #000000.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: i right clicked the mask layer and applied it and the mask "black and white" icon on that layer disappeared. thats all. tried printing and still get a gray background.

Comment: Instead of applying the mask, alt-click it to see it. Make sure you have the Info panel open. Mouse over the black area and check if it is in fact black (0, 0, 0). If it isn't, you could (while making sure the mask is still selected) use Image/Adjustments/Curves, select the black eyedropper and click inside the black area.